# Get values from D3 line interpolator functions

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am building a D3 graph which contains a shaded region in the middle of it.  The shaded regions top part matches the line graph.

[image: Shaded Graph]

The data looks something like this:

```
line = [
  {x: 0, y:1},
  {x: 1, y:2},
  {x: 2, y:4},
  {x: 3, y:6},
  {x: 4, y:3},
  {x: 5, y:1}]
```

And the graph uses a 'cardinal' interpolation function:

```
g = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate('cardinal')
```

In order to shade the area under the graph, I just create a d3.svg.area() and provide it with the equivalent data for the shaded area, e.g (to shade between x=2 and x=4):

```
area = [
  {x: 2, y:4},
  {x: 3, y:6},
  {x: 4, y:3}]
a = d3.svg.area()
 .interpolate('cardinal')
```

, but my problem is that I want to shade the area under the graph between 1.5 and 3.5 for which I dont know the values after the 'cardinal' interpolation has taken place.

So, I need to work out how to either a) apply a cardinal interpolation over the data and then pick out the values for 1.5 and 3.5 or b) extract the line data from d3 and use that to build up the data for the area graph.

for a) I have looked at d3.interpolate, but it looks like its different from d3.line.interpolate() and does not allow you to pass the interpolation method.

for b) I cant work out how to extract the data from the line once it has been interpolated... its not documented anywhere in D3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider approaching this in a different way:  you can use [svg clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) elements to arbitrarily clip a path, allowing you to forego any calculation of interpolated values.

Draw two versions of your area, one with the background styling, the other with the foreground, then create a rectangle clipPath element to bound the 'foreground' area:

js:

```
svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clipRect")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x", x(1.5))
    .attr("width", x(2))
    .attr("height", height);
```

css:

```
.foreArea {clip-path: url(#clipRect);}
```

See, for example: http://bl.ocks.org/jsl6906/89ef40de1d8808d04f42

[image: clipPath Image]

Comment: Wow, thank you.  Every day I learn something new and incredible about d3 and svg.  Works a charm.